# how to use "after_update" to pass the edited parameter to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a system that have 3 roles of user (doctor,patient,admin)
and
patient user belongs to doctor user.(to pair each patient to doctor)
I handle that by creating a new column in table user called "pair"

```
example:
user1 patient name Mr.A pair:user2
user2 doctor name Dr.D pair:null
user3 doctor name Dr.Z pair:null
```

and patient user has "msg".(another table)

```
example:
msg1:aaa own:user1 status:0, 
msg2:bbb own:user1 status:1, 
msg3:ccc own:user1 status:1
```

(own is another column I user to identify whose msg is this)

What I want to do is when admin edit "pair" in some user.
In this case if admin edit pair of user1,
I want to change all of the status of all "msg" that belong to user1 to 0

```
example:
admin edit user1 - from pair:user2 to pair:user3
then
msg1:aaa own:user1 status:0, 
msg2:bbb own:user1 status:1, 
msg3:ccc own:user1 status:1
```

here is some of my code

my user model(after_update part)(this is wrong):

```
  after_update :doMsgStatus, :if => :pair_changed?

  def doMsgStatus
    old = pair_was
    @msg = Msg.find_all_by_own(:name)
    @msg.each do |l|
      l.read = 0
      l.save
    end
  end
```

from the above code, i think param :name is empty, so rails can't find any msg_by_own and all of the msg status is the same.
Help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  your code :name represent just a symbol not the value of the name column of the current record.

If you want to search by name use self.name instead of name (name alone should work too). So your code become (I remove the @msg var since you do nothing with it)
"@my_var" is for a instance variable if you need the var only in the method just use "my_var")

```
  def doMsgStatus
    old = pair_was
    Msg.find_all_by_own(self.name).each do |l|
      l.read = 0
      l.save
    end
 end
```

Comment: thx! it's working now, but if i want to change some column in "user" table too, example: self.name=MR.aa  self.save, i got "stack too deep" error from from adding those.

Comment: it's normal your are in an after_update callback so each time a user is updated this callback is fired. So to resume you update a user and after that update you change this same user again so this fire the callback again and so on...